# Remove Overlay Lines From Video

Tags: premiere, post-production

In a bit of a panic here. I've recorded a bunch of footage and had some sort of overlay grid that appears to be baked into the video. Using Premiere or some other tool, is there a way to kill it? Sort of like a content aware fill in Photoshop. It's in the same spot throughout each clip. Is there hope?

[image: image with lines]

Comment: Might be able to help more if you tell us how it was recorded, what camera, what mode, settings etc?  

Wire Removal in After Effects, or Content Aware Fill in After Effects could work for you.  Or making a clean plate, and using that as a backdrop, and rotoscoping your foreground into it?  Davinci Resolve also has some nice cleanup tools.  Your best result would be reshooting, but you don't want to do that otherwise you wouldn't be here...

https://www.rocketstock.com/blog/4-brilliant-ways-to-remove-objects-in-after-effects/

Comment: It is an overlay from the Camo Studio app using an iPhone as the camera source. We're reshooting because I screwed up the audio as well but it's good to know that these are options. I'll check out After Effects Content aware Fill because *that* is what I was looking for.. just didn't know where to look! Thank you